# Laravel overwrite delete method on hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to overwrite the delete method on a model.

In my User model i have this code:

```
public function delete()
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->remote_id)) {
        $this->location_id = null;
        $this->save();
    } else {
        parent::delete();
    }
}
```

Basically this method deletes the record if remote_id is null. If it's not null it disconnects the user from the location by setting location_id to null.

When i do $user->delete() this method gets called and it works fine.

But when i delete all the users for a locations like this $location->users()->delete() this method does not get called. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want model methods to be used (or model events to be fired) you'll need to iterate through all users and delete each of them individually, e.g.:

```
$location->users->map(function($user) {
  $user->delete();
});
```

If you have many users, such operation might be quite time consuming, so I'd rather just update all related models instead of fetching them all and calling **delete()** on each of them:

```
$location->users()->update(['location_id' => null]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
// In App/Location.php
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::deleting(function($location) {
        foreach($location->users as $user) {
            if( ! is_null($user->remote_id) ) {
                $user->location_id = null;
                $user->save();
            }
            else {
                $user->delete();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This will delete all the `User` models depending on the `location_id` status (if `location_id` is `null`) when you delete any `Location` model, but if `location_id` is not `null` then the value of `user->location_id` will be updated to `null`.